# Laravel 4 Routing with Arbitrary Number of URL Segments

Tags: php, url-routing, laravel, laravel-4

I have an L3 application I'm trying to port to L4. In the L3 version, one of my routes is

```
Route::get('/(:any)/(:all?)', etc...
```

This allowed me to handle an arbitrary number of URL segments, for example:

```
/contact_page
/store_category
/store_category/shirts_category
/store_category/shirts_category/specific_shirt_page
/an/arbitrary/number/of/nested/categories
```

But in L4 I cannot figure out how to emulate the functionality of (:all?)

The code below works:

```
Route::get('/{arg1?}/{arg2?}/{arg3?}', function($arg1='home', $arg2, $arg3)
{
  //do something
});
```

So I could add a large number of optional arguments (more than I think I would ever need in real world use) but that is not very elegant.

Is there some way in Laravel 4 to define a Route that can respond to an arbitrary number of URL segments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a pattern condition to your route, ex.:

```
Route::get('{any}/{args}', function($action, $args = null)
{
   // do something like return print_r(explode('/', $args), true);
})->where('args', '(.*)');
```